# If $a$ ($a\ne 1$) has order $t\mod p$, show that $a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}+\cdots+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ ($a\ne 1$) has order $t\mod p$, show that $a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}+\cdots+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Since $a$ has order $t$ we have that $a^t\equiv1\pmod{p}$ or $a^t-1 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$. We also know that $a^t-1=(a-1)(a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}+\cdots+1)$.

So $0=a^t-1=(a-1)(a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}+\cdots+1)\pmod{p}$. How do I get rid of the $(a-1)$ term on the left ? Can I simply say that since $(a-1)\ne0$ and divide both sides by it and get the desired result ? Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ is a prime number, we know that $p\mid AB$ implies either $p\mid A$ or $p\mid B$.

Apply this with $A = a - 1$ and $B = a^{t - 1} + \dots + 1$ to conclude.

Comment: I understand the first sentence, but I don't understand how to apply it here. I know that $a-1\not \equiv 0$(mod $p$)

Comment: With $A$ and $B$ as in the second sentence, we have $p\mid AB$, and hence either $p \mid A$ or $p \mid B$. But $p \mid A$ is impossible, as we assume that $p \nmid a - 1$. Thus the only possibility is $p\mid B$.

Comment: I think I see this now. So $p$ does not divide $A$ because $a-1 \not \equiv 0$ (mod $p$). So it follows that $p$ divides $B$ and so $a^{t-1}+a^{t-2}+\cdots+1 \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank you for you help and dealing with my little monkey brain lol